# TSQL program to find if we have more than one deptno in that location display the first one

Tags: t-sql

Dept. table

```
deptno dname loc
100    a     xx
200    b     yy
300    c     tt
400    d     yy
500    e     pp
```

when I execute a TSQL query to display the `deptno` and `dname` whose `loc` is `yy` I get the output `400 d` but I need the first record corresponding to the loc `yy` that is `200 b`

CODE AS FOLLOWS

```
DECLARE @DNO VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @DNM VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @LOC VARCHAR(20)='YY'
BEGIN
    SELECT  @DN=DNAME,@DNO=DEPTNO
    FROM DEPT
    WHERE LOC=@LOC
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
PRINT 'INVALID'
ELSE
PRINT @DNM+ ''+@DNO
END
```

please assist me

Comment: Include your sql statement.

Comment: As has already been mentioned, please include the code you are wanting us to review/improve.

Comment: Thanks Chad Henderson and Brain sorry now I've mentioned the code

Comment: It worked like what I needed just included TOP 1 in select

Comment: You may want to add an `ORDER BY` clause so that `TOP` will return a more predictable result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you define "first record". If the order is determined by the department number, you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 deptno, dname
FROM YourTable
WHERE loc = 'yy'
ORDER BY deptno
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.deptno, 
a.dname 
from myTable as a
inner join 
    (select loc, 
    min(deptno) minDeptno
    from myTable
    group by loc) as b
on a.loc = b.loc
and a.deptno = b.minDeptno
where loc = @LOC
```

You could have the where clause in the subquery, but this just seems more reusable.